# Groovy script for escaping double quotes in JSON

Tags: json, groovy, escaping

I have a requirement wherein the output JSON field needs to have an escaped double quotes ("). I managed to have the quotes escaped in the field values by hardcoding the quotes. But now, I'm not so sure on how to put a backslash in the start and end of the field.

Please see sample below:

```
{ "Request": 

[ { 

"content": { "row": [ 

{ "fieldA": [ "tax\":\"US\",\"percent\": 6.250000000,\"value\": 10000.000000000,\"description\":\"TaxUS\",\"currency\":\"USD" ]}, 

{"fieldA": [ "tax\":\"\",\"percent\": 0.000000000,\"value\": 170000.000000000,\"description\":\"Total\",\"currency\":\"USD" ] }, 

{ "fieldB": [ "item\":\"000000\",\"Line\":0000,\"Date\":\"20201207\",\"Qty\": 2000,\"confirm\": 0.00" ] }, 

{"fieldB": [ "item\":\"000001\",\"Line\":0001,\"Date\":\"20201208\",\"Qty\": 1000,\"confirm\": 2000.00" ] } ] } }
```

I need to have a backslash at the beginning and the end of the fieldA and fieldB arrays.

This is the expected output:

```
{ "Request":

[ {

"content": { "row": [

{ "fieldA": [ \"tax\":\"US\",\"percent\": 6.250000000,\"value\": 10000.000000000,\"description\":\"TaxUS\",\"currency\":\"USD\" ]},

{"fieldA": [ \"tax\":\"\",\"percent\": 0.000000000,\"value\": 170000.000000000,\"description\":\"Total\",\"currency\":\"USD\" ] },

{ "fieldB": [ \"item\":\"000000\",\"Line\":0000,\"Date\":\"20201207\",\"Qty\": 2000,\"confirm\": 0.00\" ] },

{"fieldB": [ \"item\":\"000001\",\"Line\":0001,\"Date\":\"20201208\",\"Qty\": 1000,\"confirm\": 2000.00\" ] } ] } }
```

I would like to ask for tips in adding the backslash for the requirement.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't see any backslashes in expected output...

Comment: thanks for the comment. added the ``` to show the backslashes

Comment: Why do you need to generate invalid JSON? Are you sure you don't want
`"\"tax\"..."`?  Please add the code you have tried and how it failed
(e.g. errors, stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @XSLT, now your expected json is invalid.